# How do I resize the Xfce 4 panel on Xubuntu?

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

I'm on Xubuntu 19.10 and how do I resize the top panel as shown on the link below (Click on the link below for the picture) as it looks too small.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOs7n.png

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right click on the panel.
2. Go to

   *Panel → Panel preferences*
3. Go to tab `Display`.
4. In the section `Measurements` tweak `Row Size (pixels)`.

Comment: Thank you schrodigerscatcuriosity!